# Why does `yarn upgrade my_package` upgrade without respecting the version in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "5.2.0"
  }
}
```

I do `yarn install` first, `rxjs` becomes `5.2.0`.

Then `yarn upgrade rxjs`, it becomes `"rxjs": "^5.4.2"`

my yarn version 0.27.5

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/):

> **yarn upgrade [package | package@tag | package@version | @scope/]... [--ignore-engines]**
>
> ...
>
> [package] : When a specified package is only a name then the latest patching version of this package will be upgraded to.

This makes sense. If you want to upgrade your project, you expect the package manager to follow the declared Semver Range.

But if you want to upgrade a specific package, it updates it ***to the latest patching version***.